# "Borrowed Value Does Not Live Long Enough" when pushing into a vector

Tags: list, vector, rust

I am trying a [daily programmer problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3e0hmh/20150720_challenge_224_easy_shuffling_a_list/) to shuffle a list of arguments and output them.

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach but it sounded like a good idea: remove the element from the args vector so it doesn't get repeated, and insert it into the result vector.

```rust
extern crate rand; // 0.7.3

use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::env;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let mut result: Vec<_> = Vec::with_capacity(args.capacity());

    if args.len() > 1 {
        println!("There are(is) {} argument(s)", args.len() - 1)
    }

    for x in args.iter().skip(1) {
        let mut n = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, args.len());
        result.push(&args.swap_remove(n));
    }

    for y in result.iter() {
        println!("{}", y);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:18:22
   |
18 |         result.push(&args.swap_remove(n));
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                      |
   |                      creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
21 |     for y in result.iter() {
   |              ------ borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

Older compilers said:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:42
   |
18 |         result.push(&args.swap_remove(n));
   |                      ------------------- ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |                      |
   |                      temporary value created here
...
24 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with a smaller example. This is called an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , and is very valuable for both you as a programmer and for us to answer your question. Additionally, it can run on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/), which is convenient.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut args = vec!["a".to_string()];
    let mut result = vec![];

    for _ in args.iter() {
        let n = args.len() - 1; // Pretend this is a random index
        result.push(&args.swap_remove(n));
    }

    for y in result.iter() {
        println!("{}", y);
    }
}
```

The problem arises because when you call `swap_remove`, the item is *moved* out of the vector and given to you - the ownership is transferred. You then take a reference to the item and try to store that reference in the `result` vector. The problem is that the item is dropped after the loop iteration has ended because *nothing owns it*. If you were allowed to take that reference, it would be a *dangling reference*, one that points to invalid memory. Using that reference could cause a crash, so Rust prevents it.

The immediate fix is to not take a reference, but instead transfer ownership from one vector to the other. Something like:

```rust
for _ in args.iter() {
    let n = args.len() - 1; // Pretend this is a random index
    result.push(args.swap_remove(n));
}
```

The problem with this is that you will get

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `args` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:7:21
  |
5 |     for _ in args.iter() {
  |              -----------
  |              |
  |              immutable borrow occurs here
  |              immutable borrow later used here
6 |         let n = args.len() - 1;
7 |         result.push(args.swap_remove(n));
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

See the `args.iter`? That creates an iterator that refers to the vector. If you changed the vector, then the iterator would become invalid, and allow access to an item that may not be there, another potential crash that Rust prevents.

I'm not making any claim that this is a good way to do it, but one solution would be to iterate while there are still items:

```rust
while !args.is_empty() {
    let n = args.len() - 1; // Pretend this is a random index
    result.push(args.swap_remove(n));
}
```

I'd solve the overall problem by using [`shuffle`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.3/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.shuffle):

```rust
use rand::seq::SliceRandom; // 0.8.3
use std::env; 

fn main() {
    let mut args: Vec<_> = env::args().skip(1).collect();

    args.shuffle(&mut rand::thread_rng());

    for y in &args {
        println!("{}", y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, i had run into both those errors. I now have a better understanding of ownership

Comment: Could you use `into_iter()` in this situation instead? So that the iterator can be mutable?

Comment: @Danny did you try it? Did it work? If you mean in the example that says `for x in args.iter()`, then no, because changing that call to `into_iter()` would take ownership of the arguments and then you wouldn't be able to remove an argument or get the length.